# How can I export HTML table to Excel using Mozilla 3.6?

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

I have a table in HTML format.

```
<table  id="table" title="banner"  border="1" align="center" >
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Month</th><th>Savings</th></tr>
<tr><td>101</td><td>Ramesh</td><td>January</td><td>$100</td></tr>
<tr><td>102</td><td>Ram</td><td>Feb</td><td>$200</td></tr>
<tr><td>103</td><td>Ramna</td><td>Mar</td><td>$300</td></tr>
</table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using Mozilla 3.6 .so any on help me how  can I export the results to Excel sheet ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html table to csv table with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497494/html-table-to-csv-table-with-image)

Comment: Exporting directly to a native Excel file format is non-trivial, if not impossible with JS. But exporting to CSV isn't too hard, and I could post something, if that'd be an option for you. Oh, and your markup is invalid - the link and that image doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think HTML is the technology you are looking for. If you have a CSV file it can be imported into EXCEL to view the information.

Answer (score 0):

This can  only be properly done on the server. Most common way is to use a library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for Java.